# Tile column and row number in GetTile request

Tags: tiles, wmts, sentinel-hub

I try to configure WMTS for SentinelHub layers. I need to set tile rows and tile columns in GetTile request. Cannot understand how to match real coordinates (EPSG 4326 or EPSG 3857) with appropriate tile. In other words how to get appriopriate tile column and row numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the TileMatrixSet which gives you the origin, the size of the tiles and how many there are. From that its fairly simple maths to work out the tile column and row numbers by division.

Here's the [GeoTools code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/ec7dfc16a91959e31823ac5dc9ea10d464dcde26/modules/extension/wmts/src/main/java/org/geotools/ows/wmts/client/WMTSTileService.java#L843) that does the calculation:

```
    WMTSZoomLevel zl = (WMTSZoomLevel) zoomLevel;
    TileMatrix tileMatrix = getMatrixSet().getMatrices().get(zl.getZoomLevel());

    double pixelSpan = WMTSTileFactory.getPixelSpan(tileMatrix);

    double tileSpanY = (tileMatrix.getTileHeight() * pixelSpan);
    double tileSpanX = (tileMatrix.getTileWidth() * pixelSpan);
    double tileMatrixMinX;
    double tileMatrixMaxY;
    if (tileMatrix
            .getCrs()
            .getCoordinateSystem()
            .getAxis(0)
            .getDirection()
            .equals(AxisDirection.EAST)) {
        tileMatrixMinX = tileMatrix.getTopLeft().getX();
        tileMatrixMaxY = tileMatrix.getTopLeft().getY();
    } else {
        tileMatrixMaxY = tileMatrix.getTopLeft().getX();
        tileMatrixMinX = tileMatrix.getTopLeft().getY();
    }
    // to compensate for floating point computation inaccuracies
    double epsilon = 1e-6;
    long xTile = (int) Math.floor((lon - tileMatrixMinX) / tileSpanX + epsilon);
    long yTile = (int) Math.floor((tileMatrixMaxY - lat) / tileSpanY + epsilon);

    // sanitize
    xTile = Math.max(0, xTile);
    yTile = Math.max(0, yTile);
```

**But** you probably shouldn't be doing this by hand any reasonably smart library that can handle WMTS should be able to do this already and we don't really need any more libraries than the ones we already have.

Comment: Thanks, I see all possible values of tile matrix set using GetCapabilities request, I see maximum value of tile row and column for each zoom level. But can you give a link to some of the library or at least a formula to calculate row and column.

Comment: have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/405001/how-to-determine-insert-point-of-each-wmts-tile which has some code going in the other direction that comes from https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/extension/wmts/src/main/java/org/geotools/ows/wmts/client/WMTSTileFactory.java but I don't think we ever go in the other direction

Comment: Now I search harder there is this - https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/ec7dfc16a91959e31823ac5dc9ea10d464dcde26/modules/extension/wmts/src/main/java/org/geotools/ows/wmts/client/WMTSTileService.java#L841 which should do what you want